# Preventing UIImage resize for a UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios5

I have a UIButton with no text and have 2 images I'd like to use (one for normal state and the other for selected state). The images are smaller than the button size.

How do I ensure that neither of the images are scaled when the button is drawn? Setting the imageView properties only change the scale correctly for normal state but not for selected.

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button setImage:imageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:imageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    // this shows the correct scale in normal mode but not when button is tapped
    button.imageView.contentScaleFactor = 1.0;
    button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

Comment: **NOTE!!!** only the background image is stretched by default to match the frame. Use the "image" and not background image, if you want it centered

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you have the image height and width you could do this:

```
int topBottom = (button.frame.size.height - imageHeight) / 2;
int leftRight = (button.frame.size.width - imageWidth) / 2;

button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(topBottom,leftRight,topBottom,leftRight);
```

And then you don't need to set the contentMode/scalefactor.